# Algorithm to calculate rating

Tags: algorithms

First of all I must state that I am not a mathematician, so please correct me if I use wrong terminology.

I'm developing a Web application to measure the quality of businesses. Let me tell you something. Every business has 8 points at the start. Members can score between 0 and 10 points. The business's score can be up to 10. I need an algorithm for this. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Every business will be scored separately. But I am looking for a neat algorithm because there will be a problem between a company with 10 votes and a company with 1000 votes.

Exam :

- Company 1
- Start Score : 8p
- Vote used 1 : 5p
- Vote used 2 : 8p
- Vote used 3 : 1p
- Vote used 4 : 3p
- Vote used 5 : 10p
- Company 2
- Start Score : 8p
- Vote used 1 : 3p
- Vote used 2 : 8p
- Vote used 3 : 9p
- Vote used 4 : 10p
- Vote used 5 : 10p
- Vote used 6 : 10p
- Vote used 7 : 7p
- Vote used 8 : 1p
- Vote used 9 : 1p
- Vote used 10 : 1p

Other Exam:
Imdb Ratings :
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/ratings?ref_=tt_ov_rt

Comment: Maybe let the rating be a (weighted) average of the individual ratings? For example: $(0.5) \times 8 + (0.5) \times (x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n)$ where $x_1, \cdots , x_n$ are the scores.

Comment: I think we'd be willing to help you if you edit the question to make it clear. An example would do. Provide us with some sample data (made up) for a business. How many points does it have now? What are various member scores and what do they mean? Approximately what quality rating would make sense to you given these numbers?

Comment: yes every business will be scored separately. But I am looking for a neat algorithm because there will be a problem between a company with 10 votes and a company with 1000 votes.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ to clarify. It's hard for us to read changes that are sprinkled into comments. And give us some sample data.

Comment: I added a sample

Comment: Perhaps you could interpret the ratings as a sample from a putative underlying "distribution of ratings", construct a 90% confidence interval for the mean of the underlying distribution, and display the lower bound of the interval? This will give a bit of a boost to companies with more ratings. (Note: idea adapted from here: https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)

Comment: @ConnorHarris That's a very interesting link. But it deals with finding an average or summary of yes/no votes. The OP has richer data. If there's a way to adapt this someone will have to tell the OP how.

Comment: There are as many algorithms as people care to write.  *You* need to think about what you want.  "Always return 8$ is a fine algorithm.  "Average all the votes, returning 8 if there are none" is another.  You have some (probably vague) ideas for how it should work.  You need to make those ideas precise before an algorithm can be written.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think that scores out of 10 offer a wide enough range to use the standard inferential-statistics approach: if the mean and standard deviation of the $N$ ratings for a business are $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then assume that the possible values of the true score of the business follow a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{N}$, then return $\mu - z \sigma/\sqrt{N}$ for some fixed parameter $z$ as the score for the business. The link basically adapts this approach to Bernoulli distributions, which are a bit harder to work with.

Answer (score 1):

A voting database, that I know quite well, uses a weighing of the arithmetic mean. 
This is done, by calculating the usual arithmetic mean of the $n$ votes and multiplies this by $\frac{n-1}{n}$ to get the score.

This will put an often rated company at a higher score, than a less often rated company, even though it has the same average vote.

Comment: Interesting. But it does mean that you can't have a score that's a perfect $10$ even if every customer loves you.

Comment: Right, there is no perfect scoring. If you want to look at it this ways: The exposure (amount of people voting) is also a good indication of quality.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear how you want to use the starting rating of $8$. One possibility is to use it less and less the more actual votes you have. That suggests this variant on @AlexLostado 's comment: count the initial $8$ as if it were some fixed number of votes. For example, if that fixed number were $10$ votes then the rating for company 1 would be
$$
\frac{10 \times 8 + 8 + 5 + 8 + 1 + 3 + 10}{10 + 5}.
$$
That's the ordinary average of $10$ starting votes and the $5$ actual customer votes. You could give more or less weight to the start by increasing or decreasing the $10$.

Comment: what I want to do is basically calculating the imdb score.

Comment: I think the imdb score is just the plain old arithmetic average. Instead of adding $7+7 + \cdots$ for all the votes of $7$ and similarly for other votes and dividing by the total number of votes just multiply $7$ by the percentage of $7$ votes, and so on, and add.